# How do I make my personal github represent the things I have done with gitlab. It's possible?

Tags: github, gitlab

I have worked hard with corporate gitlab. How do I make my personal github represent the things I have done with gitlab. It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

(assuming your code on GitLab isn't proprietary..) you can use repository mirroring. Push mirroring is open source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pushing-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: Thank you. I'll try here and talk to work people to see if it's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not proprietary,there are two things you can do:
1.  You can clone the repositories then then push them to a new remote which will be github , here you may also delete all git files and reinitialize the project and push to github.
2. You can just copy the clone url from the cooperate repo and go to github and click add repository , select import repository then paste in your clone url

Comment: Thank you. I'll try here and talk to work people to see if it's allowed.